# Displaying the time from database in a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetimepicker

I have a column (datatype is `time(7)`) in my SQL Server database to store the time. When I try to retrieve that value from the database and display it in a `DateTimePicker` (format set to display time only), it throws an `InvalidCastException` error.

This is the line where the casting happens.

```
r = com.ExecuteReader();
dtpOutTime.Value = (DateTime)r["OutTime"];
```

I can understand why the error is thrown but I can't figure out a way to correct it.

How can I display only the time from database in a `DateTimePicker`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `System.Data.DbType.Time` you use the .NET Framework type `System.TimeSpan`.

for example:

```
dtpOutTime.Value = DateTime.Today + (TimeSpan)r["OutTime"];
```

(if you want to add the TimeSpan to `Today` midnight and the timespan would be 6 hours, the result would be `10/22/2012 6:00:00 AM`)